# mac ports python32 tkinter module not loading

Tags: python, tkinter, macports

not able to launch my python script. It is complaining that Tkinter module is nowhere to be found....

Uhm, what am I missing?

```
 from Tkinter import * ImportError: No module named Tkinter


$ sudo port installed | grep py  
py32-tkinter @3.2.2_0 (active) 
python32 @3.2.2_0 (active)
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does the output of `python -c "import sys;print sys.path"` look like? Can you get ports to give you a list of the all the files it has associated with the py32-tkinter package?